# C#: Multi-Thread download

Tags: c#, multithreading

Basically, I have two main thread. One is in charge of downloading data. The other is in charge of inserting the data into sqlite database. The inserting thread keeps inserting until it finds the downloading one finishes its job.

My question is, how should I judge the downloading one is completed? I know I can use Task.IsCompleted to get the signal. But it is a little complicated in the downloading thread. I used a foreach-block and in which there is a new sub-thread is open in every loop. I used a new task to contain the whole foreach-block and try to get the new task's Task.IsCompleted, but when Task.IsCompleted is true, the sub-threads are not finished, they are still running. So how should I konw when all the download threads end? Then I can jump out of the while-true block.

```
private Task BeginDownload(PackageCategory type)
{
    if (IsMagazineSelected)
    {
       ObservableCollection<Category_Info> categorylist = new ObservableCollection<Category_Info>() { };
       foreach (var category in MagazineCategoryList)
       {
          if (category.IsChecked && category.IsEnabled)
          {
             categorylist.Add(category);
             _allData.MagazineCount += category.MagazineList.Count;
          }
       }
       _allData.CollectCategoryData(categorylist);

       if (MagazineCategoryTask != null)
       {
           while (true)
           {
              if (MagazineCategoryTask.IsCompleted)
              {

                 DownloadMagazinePartTask = Task.Run(delegate
                 {
                     foreach (var category in categorylist)
                        {
                             category.IsEnabled = false;
                             category.MagazineList.ForEach(x => x.CategoryCode = category.CategoryCode);

                              _allData.CollectMagazineData(category.MagazineList);

                              if (!category.TotalCount.Equals("0"))
                              {
                                    DownloadMagazinePartTask1 = Task.Run(async delegate
                                    {
                                        LogHelper.LogInfo(string.Format("*************Begin to download the Latest magazines; Category id: {0}, name {1}.", category.CategoryCode, category.CategoryName));

                                        await DownloadMagazineTask(type, category.MagazineList).ContinueWith(anc =>
                                        {
                                            DownloadMagazinePartTask = Task.Run(delegate
                                            {
                                            LogHelper.LogInfo(string.Format("*************Begin to download History magazines; Category id: {0}, name {1}.", category.CategoryCode, category.CategoryName));

                                            foreach (var magazine in category.MagazineList)
                                            {
                                                MagazineService.GetHistoryMagazineByMagazineGuid(magazine.MagazineGUID).ContinueWith(async ancc =>
                                                {
                                                    List<Magazine_Info> historyMagazines = GetMagazineListFromResult(ancc.Result);
                                                    historyMagazines.RemoveAt(0);
                                                    historyMagazines.ForEach(x =>
                                                    {
                                                        x.MagazineGUID = magazine.MagazineGUID;
                                                        x.CategoryCode = magazine.CategoryCode;
                                                        x.CodeName = magazine.CodeName;
                                                        x.IconList = magazine.IconList;
                                                    });

                                                    _allData.CollectMagazineData(historyMagazines);
                                                    _allData.MagazineCount += historyMagazines.Count;
                                                    LogHelper.LogInfo(string.Format("Download {0} history magazines! Magazine name is {1}, Guid is {2}", historyMagazines.Count, magazine.MagazineName, magazine.MagazineGUID));

                                                    await DownloadMagazineTask(type, historyMagazines, true);
                                                });

                                            }

                                        });

                                    });
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }




        Task.Run(delegate 
        {
            int times = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (_allData.MagazineList != null && _allData.MagazineList.Count != 0) 
                { 
                    int rownum = MagazineService.InsertMagazines(_allData.MagazineList);
                    LogHelper.LogInfo(String.Format("Times: {0}: Insert Magazines: {1} in total {2}", times.ToString(), _allData.MagazineList.Count, rownum));
                }
                if (_allData.CatalogList != null && _allData.CatalogList.Count != 0) 
                {
                    bool insertResult = CatalogService.InsertCatalogs(_allData.CatalogList);
                    LogHelper.LogInfo(String.Format("Times: {0}: Insert Catalogs: {1}", times.ToString(), _allData.CatalogList.Count.ToString()));
                }
                if (_allData.MagazineArticleList != null && _allData.MagazineArticleList.Count != 0) 
                { 
                    bool insertArticleResult = MagazineArticleService.InsertArticles(_allData.MagazineArticleList);
                    LogHelper.LogInfo(String.Format("Times: {0}: Insert Articles: {1}", times.ToString(), _allData.MagazineArticleList.Count.ToString()));
                }

                if (_allData.MagazineList != null && _allData.CatalogList != null && _allData.MagazineArticleList != null)
                {
                    DownloadMagazinePartTask.Wait();
                    if (DownloadMagazinePartTask.IsCompleted && DownloadMagazinePartTask1.IsCompleted) //If the downloading thread is completed, I need to jump out here 
                    {
                        MagazineService.InsertMagazines(_allData.MagazineList);
                        CatalogService.InsertCatalogs(_allData.CatalogList);
                        MagazineArticleService.InsertArticles(_allData.MagazineArticleList);
                        LogHelper.LogInfo("All Insert Work is Done! Quit!");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                times++;

            }


        });

        return Task.FromResult<string>(null);
    }
```

Comment: it's not a matter of getting answer to specific coding/understanding question. In essense, you are asking somebody to re-design a software for you.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear. I just want to know how could I know when the task ends. Then I can jump out of the while-true block.

Comment: There is only one main thread.

Comment: @Mare Infinitus , yes, only one main thread. I mean I open two threads and then there are some sub-threads under the two threads.

Comment: Does I see a Consumer Producer problem in here :D ??? i think you can base your answer on that

Comment: @KCdod , yep, kind of Producer–consumer problem, but what I really care about is how should I know Producer is done. And my Producer here is not produce data always.

Comment: what your producer produce :D ?? Is it a file ? Or you read something. I might suggest you an answer if you could tell us what they are :)

Comment: @KCdod What I download is some pictures. I have some different categories of pictures. First, I get the categories info. Every category is gotten in one single thread. Then every category info provides me some sub-categories. I get the every sub-category in one single thread too. Then sub-category info tells me which picture should I download. Is that clear?

Comment: have you tried this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997417(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: also task completion event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx

i think You don't need that while loop.. if you execute your task hierarchy properly you can achieve your goal without it.. also use producer-consumer solution to organize your threads properly :)